# My db is gone and a table is gone after trying to do some tests

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I had three table in my DB that I changed during the development. `Users`, `Foods` and `Entries.` I tried to do some tests but it would always give an error because the test database had old parameters for the tables which were changed. I tried to migrate but it was not working. So stupid me did this:

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

It started giving me new errors. Weird ones. Like "table entries does not exist". I went to mysql console to check and in fact, the table is gone! Tables users and foods are still there but empty! What have I done? How do I revert back?

BTW I created users and foods as scaffolds and entries just as a model. Maybe that's why the former didn't get deleted?

EDIT: Also it looks like my remaining tables downgraded to the initial state. The columns are the ones I had during the creation of the scaffolds.

Comment: How existent is your back-up policy

Comment: only updating my git repository

Comment: The data lost is no big deal. But I'd like at least my tables back. The models are still there and the schema is still alright in the app. What should I do now?

Comment: **Tip:** Always use `RAILS_ENV` before the command to avoid issues. Sometimes it doesn't work if you pass it after the command e.g. `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create`

Comment: but why did it erase my development db while I added "=test"?

Comment: you don't happen to have test and development set to use the same db by any chance do you in your database.yml configuration?

Comment: @Deepak oh, interesting. I didn't know that, good to know. Is that a random issue or under certain circumstances when putting it after the command might not work.

Comment: no, I have name_development and name_test @david

Comment: ok ... was a long shot but worth clarifying. Maybe Deepak is right and your RAILS_ENV was ignored for whatever reason. Try a `db:reset` followed by `db:migrate` on your development environment to get it back to what it should be.